# std::vector<unsigned char> remains empty after reading binary file using std::ifstream

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, stdvector, ifstream

This is my first question on StackOverflow so I apologize in advance if there is anything I am missing in my question or some rule I didn't follow. Please edit my question or tell me in the comments how I should improve my question, thank you.

I am trying to read a binary file into a `std::vector<unsigned char>` in C++ using `std::ifstream`. The problem is that it appears the file was read successfully, but the vector remains empty.

Here is the function that I used for reading the file:

```
void readFile(const std::string &fileName, std::vector<unsigned char> &fileContent)
{
    std::ifstream in(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);

    // reserve capacity
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileContent.reserve(in.tellg());
    in.clear();
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read into vector
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(fileContent.data()), fileContent.capacity());

    if(in)
        std::cout << "all content read successfully: " << in.gcount() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "error: only " << in.gcount() << " could be read" << std::endl;

    in.close();
}
```

And this is how I called the function in `main()`:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buf;
readFile("file.dat", buf);
std::cout << "buf size: " << buf.size() << std::endl;
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
all content read successfully: 323
buf size: 0
```

When I try to print the items in the vector like this:

```
for(const auto &i : buf)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)i;
}
std::cout << std::dec << std::endl;
```

I get empty output.

#### Things I have checked

- `file.dat` is in the same directory as the program
- `file.dat` is not empty

So, is there anything I did wrong? Why is the vector empty after reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reserve()` allocates memory, but it doesn't register the allocated region as valid elements.

You should use `resize()` to add elements and `size()` to count the elements.

```
    // reserve capacity
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    //fileContent.reserve(in.tellg());
    fileContent.resize(in.tellg());
    in.clear();
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read into vector
    //in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(fileContent.data()), fileContent.capacity());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(fileContent.data()), fileContent.size());
```